# Automatic Daily EMA adjustment

Tags: pine-script

I have a 5 EMA indicator which I want to convert as follows.

I want the horizontal lines, which I currently move manually every day to the Current EMA value (and then make the EMA indicator invisible so that only the H lines are visible) to be aligned automatically.

I have already worked with several ready-made code fragments, but I just cannot find a solution. I tried with "24x7", "00:00" and the corresponding commands etc. but I can't get it. Also I don't want the lines from the day before to be visible. You know what I mean? It should just automatically move my H lines to the value of the respective EMAs at 00:00. I have been searching in Google for ages, but I can't find anything I can work with as a beginner.

````
//5 Horizontal EMA by -=Tre$aCo7n=-
//Modified from 4 Exponential Moving Averages from @vitastrato

study(title="5 Horizontal EMA", shorttitle="5 H. EMA", overlay=true)

len1 = input(10, minval=8, title="Length")
len2 = input(21, minval=8, title="Length")
len3 = input(55, minval=8, title="Length")
len4 = input(100, minval=8, title="Length")
len5 = input(200, minval=8, title="Length")

src = input(close, title="Source")

entryema = ema(src, len1)
fastema = ema(src, len2)
mediumema = ema(src, len3)
slowema = ema(src, len4)
veryslowema = ema(src, len5)

plot(entryema, color=green, linewidth=3, title="Entry EMA")
plot(fastema, color=orange, linewidth=3, title="Fast EMA")
plot(mediumema, color=red, linewidth=3, title="Medium EMA")
plot(slowema, color=white, linewidth=3, title="Slow EMA")
plot(veryslowema, color=purple, linewidth=3, title="Veryslow EMA")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will plot what you need.
The cutoff time `00:00` is expressed in Exchange Time.

```
//@version=4
//5 Horizontal EMA by -=Tre$aCo7n=-
//Modified from 4 Exponential Moving Averages from @vitastrato

study(title="5 Horizontal EMA", shorttitle="5 H. EMA", overlay=true)

len1 = input(10, minval=8, title="Length")
len2 = input(21, minval=8, title="Length")
len3 = input(55, minval=8, title="Length")
len4 = input(100, minval=8, title="Length")
len5 = input(200, minval=8, title="Length")
src  = input(close, title="Source")

var bool show_hlines = input(true, "Show horizontal lines", input.bool)
var bool show_emas   = not show_hlines

var color_entryema    = color.green
var color_fastema     = color.orange
var color_mediumema   = color.red
var color_slowema     = color.white
var color_veryslowema = color.purple

var line_entryema    = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=show_hlines ? color_entryema    : na, style=line.style_dashed)
var line_fastema     = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=show_hlines ? color_fastema     : na, style=line.style_dashed)
var line_mediumema   = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=show_hlines ? color_mediumema   : na, style=line.style_dashed)
var line_slowema     = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=show_hlines ? color_slowema     : na, style=line.style_dashed)
var line_veryslowema = line.new(x1=na, y1=na, x2=na, y2=na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, extend=extend.right, color=show_hlines ? color_veryslowema : na, style=line.style_dashed)

f_moveLine(_id, _x, _y) =>
    line.set_xy1(_id, _x,   _y)
    line.set_xy2(_id, _x+1, _y)

entryema    = ema(src, len1)
fastema     = ema(src, len2)
mediumema   = ema(src, len3)
slowema     = ema(src, len4)
veryslowema = ema(src, len5)

if (hour==0 and minute==0 and year(time)==year(timenow) and month(time)==month(timenow) and dayofmonth(time)==dayofmonth(timenow))
    f_moveLine(line_entryema,    time, entryema)
    f_moveLine(line_fastema,     time, fastema)
    f_moveLine(line_mediumema,   time, mediumema)
    f_moveLine(line_slowema,     time, slowema)
    f_moveLine(line_veryslowema, time, veryslowema)
    
plot(entryema,    color=show_emas ? color_entryema    : na, linewidth=1, title="Entry EMA")
plot(fastema,     color=show_emas ? color_fastema     : na, linewidth=1, title="Fast EMA")
plot(mediumema,   color=show_emas ? color_mediumema   : na, linewidth=1, title="Medium EMA")
plot(slowema,     color=show_emas ? color_slowema     : na, linewidth=1, title="Slow EMA")
plot(veryslowema, color=show_emas ? color_veryslowema : na, linewidth=1, title="Veryslow EMA")
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much Mate!! That's awesome. I really appreciate that... honestly speechless.

Comment: You're welcome. If you feel that it solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted so that others can benefit from it too. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Mr. Mistiaen. Thank you again for your help with the horizontal EMA`s. I have another question regarding Labeling the Lines. I have managed to display the "Weekly Close" as a label with the following and more code lines. But now I try in vain to label the horizontal EMAs with 10, 21 etc. Is it possible that this does not work because they are variables?

Comment: Could you post a new question for that please? It's against SO's house rules to aggregate multiple problems into 1 question.

Comment: Done, thanks for that info.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142238/label-horizontal-ema-lines-variables