# How to extend a moving average using its last 2 data points as gradient to draw trend line

Tags: plot, pine-script, moving-average, trendline

extend.right does not work when trying to extend the MA out on a current trend.
I believe the answer is to draw a line extending out from the MA coordinates into the future (to the right).
The gradient of the MA should be the gradient of the trend line drawn.
To do this I believe it may be necessary to take the last 2 data points of the MA to establish the current gradient. Then apply this gradient to the trend line. (And yes the change in the current period price will alter the data point of the current MA, this should result in the drawn trend line adjusting in gradient accordingly in real time).

The closest other example I could find is in the link below - however the below answer seems to plot a line at the current EMA level taken from the current period. It does not take the gradient of the current EMA to plot the line.

[How to extend a moving average plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267582/how-to-extend-a-moving-average-plot)

The code I have currently is simply the MA... I am stuck and struggling to start.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//MA21
lenghtMA21 = input(21, minval=1, title="Length")
sourceMA21 = input(close, title="Source")
offsetMA21 = input(title="Offset", type=input.integer, defval=-2, minval=-500, maxval=500)
outMA21 = sma(sourceMA21, lenghtMA21)
plot(outMA21, color=color.green, linewidth=2, title="MA", offset=offsetMA21)

//MA21 forecaster
// draw a line that extends from the moving average to 6 periods into the future. 
// take the current gradient of the moving average to draw this line.
// help!
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do a little math to determine the coordinates of the future point. Given two (x,y) coordinates, you can determine the future (x,y) for the line's end point.

Given you want it 6 bars into future, we already have the end point's x value (`bar_index + 6`) and we can calculate the new y value from that given you are using the current and last bar's MA (x,y) coordinates.

```
f_y_given_x(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2, _new_x) =>
    _m = (_y2 - _y1) / (_x2 - _x1)
    _b = _y1 - _m * _x1
    _new_y = _m * _new_x + _b
    _new_y

ma = ema(close, 30)

var ma_line = line.new(x1 = na, y1 = na, x2 = na, y2 = na, color = color.fuchsia, extend = extend.none)

x1 = bar_index - 1
y1 = ma[1]
x2 = bar_index
y2 = ma

x3 = bar_index + 6
y3 = f_y_given_x(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3)

line.set_xy1(ma_line, x = x1, y = y1)
line.set_xy2(ma_line, x = x3, y = y3)

plot(ma, color = color.fuchsia)
```