# How to plot beyond the last bar in TradingView Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm looking for a way to adding some additional bars after the last bar on the chart, and based on the bars extending the indicators on the chart so I can TA based on the future indicator values beyond the last indicator values on the realtime last bar.

For example, how is it possible to add let's say a bar OHLC `27360, 27460, 27160, 27260` to a last bar Close `27360` on a chart with a `SMA(close, 200)` extending itself for the 1 bar? If it's not possible, what would be a simpler solution or a workaround?

Comment: For SMA, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982397/how-to-extend-a-moving-average-using-its-last-2-data-points-as-gradient-to-draw)

Answer (score 0):

For OHLC4, use [line.new](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_line%7Bdot%7Dnew)
Something like this:

```
var line lh = na
line.delete(lh[1])
if barstate.islast
    lh := line.new(bar_index, ohlc4, bar_index+1, ohlc4, width=2, color=color.red, extend=extend.right)
```

For SMA extend, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68982397/how-to-extend-a-moving-average-using-its-last-2-data-points-as-gradient-to-draw)

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Extended Indicator Example", overlay=true)

// Define the length of the extended data series (in bars)
extended_length = input.int(title="extended_length", defval=100)
var float extended_close = na

// Calculate the value for the extended bar
if barstate.islast
    extended_close := close + ((close[1] - close) / (1 + extended_length))

// Plot the extended data series as a line
plot(extended_close, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, title="Extended Close")

// Plot the original close as a line
plot(close, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Close")

// Define the length of the SMA
length = input.int(200, minval=1)

// Define the source series for the SMA
src = input(close, title="Source")

// Define the custom SMA function
sma1(src, length, extended_data) =>
    sma_value = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        if i < extended_length
            sma_value := sma_value + extended_data[i]
        else
            sma_value := sma_value + src[i - extended_length]
    sma_value := sma_value / length
    sma_value

// Define the regular SMA function
sma2(src, length) =>
    sma_value1 = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        sma_value1 := sma_value1 + src[i]
    sma_value1 := sma_value1 / length
    sma_value1

// Calculate the SMA using the custom function
sma_value1 = sma2(src, length)

// Plot the SMA
plot(sma_value1, title="regular SMA", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
// Calculate and plot a 200-period SMA based on the extended data series
extended_data = close + ((close[1] - close) / (1 + extended_length))
extended_sma = sma1(src, length, extended_data)
plot(extended_sma, color=color.green, linewidth=2, title="Extended SMA")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Right but what would be the reason to close the trade beyond stop loss u need to b more specific and that's not really how strategys in general work u usually close because the bot took the opposite trade or because of stop loss. I mean it should be possible to add a time based exit like if 10 bars or X hours/days go by exit trade